# Adding to an associate array in PHP using a loop

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
$usepassArray = explode(",", $implodedstuff);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($usepassArray) ; $i = $i + 2)
{
    $finalArray += array($usepassArray[$i] => $usepassArray[$i + 1]);
}
```

So my $usepassArray is an 8 string long array of usernames and passwords. So $usepassArray[0] is the username, and [1] is the password. Im trying to make a associate array to pair up these usernames and passwords. I cant figure out how to append this to the end of the array, for some reason += is returning an error and I have been searching the internet for hours and nothing is working. The closest I have gotten is an array whithin an array.

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: So I tried $finalArray[] = and im getting this weird array in array thing   array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["beavis"]=> string(8) "password" } [1]=> array(1) { ["butthead"]=> string(9) "password2" } [2]=> array(1) { ["dana"]=> string(5) "alien" } [3]=> array(1) { ["fox"]=> string(7) "believe" } }

Comment: Show the input and expected output.

Comment: why no `array_push()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what your desired final structure is. If it's an array of username/password pair arrays, then you can just change this line:

```
$finalArray += array($usepassArray[$i] => $usepassArray[$i + 1]);
```

to

```
$finalArray[] = array($usepassArray[$i] => $usepassArray[$i + 1]);
```

This will give you a structure that looks something like this:

```
[['user1' => 'pass1'],
 ['user2' => 'pass2'],
 ...
 ['usern' => 'passn']
]
```

If on the other hand you don't want that level of nesting, i.e. you want something that looks like this:

```
['user1' => 'pass1',
 'user2' => 'pass2',
 ...
 'usern' => 'passn'
]
```

Then change that line to this:

```
$finalArray[$usepassArray[$i]] = $usepassArray[$i + 1];
```